# Assign value to uninitialized ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, gcc

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int num = 30;
    int *ptr;
    *ptr = num;
    
    std::cout << *ptr; // print 30
    std::cout << ptr; // memorry address - 0
}
```

This code is legal for [gcc 4.9.2](http://ideone.com/txa2ll)
Why error doesn't occur? What sense to store the assigned value in the uninitialized ptr? How it possible to store value in the uninitialized ptr?
I guess this is undefined behavior because uninitialized ptr contain garbage and therefore he can point to random memmory and compiler think that this is ok until I make `int *ptr = NULL;`? I can't check this assumption because ptr adrress is always `0`.

Comment: you have undefined behavior. You have not set ptr to a valid value

Comment: well it is undefined behavior, I guess the compiler just optimized all the assignments away and printed the values straight ahead

Comment: This is undefined behavior. It doesn't need to crash, the behavior is undefined. That may include crashing, or may include appearing to work fine.

Comment: Welcome to C++, if you want to shoot yourself in the foot, we will let you. (or if you prefer "with great power comes great responsibility")

Comment: "I guess this is undefined behavior" - yes, so anything might happen. Anything includes "print 30".

Comment: Set the appropriate warning level and the compiler does [tell you](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/16b0a7ddcbecdd76) you're doing something wrong. Choose to ignore compiler warnings and you'll reap what you sow.

Comment: The code may be *compilable*. But compilable code doesn't mean defined-behavior. As-written you can't even *evaluate* `ptr` and have defined behavior (such as your `std::cout << ptr;`) , much less *dereference* it and eval the result.

Comment: The code has nothing to do with the question title. "Assigning value to an uninitialized pointer" is perfectly fine: `int num = 30; int *ptr; /* uninitialized */ ptr = &num; /* assigned-to */`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The code is syntactically correct and always consistently has undefined behaviour.**

An uninitialized variable including pointers do not have any defined value and assigning values to a pointer variable can have varied result, none of which are defined.

**Section 4.1 looks like a candidate (emphasis mine):**

> An lvalue (3.10) of a non-function, non-array type T can be converted
>   to an rvalue. If T is an incomplete type, a program that necessitates
>   this conversion is ill-formed. If the object to which the lvalue
>   refers is not an object of type T and is not an object of a type
>   derived from T, or if the object is uninitialized, a program that
>   necessitates this conversion has undefined behavior. If T is a
>   non-class type, the type of the rvalue is the cv-unqualified version
>   of T. Otherwise, the type of the rvalue is T.

Answer (score 1):

> This code is legal for gcc 4.9.2

No, it's not.

Don't mistake "doesn't produce an error" for "is legal".

In general compilers cannot diagnose invalid pointer accesses, so they don't. That's your job!

Answer (score 0):

Your code line `int *ptr` is a defination, not an initialization, therefore compiler does not assign any resource (register or memory to the value).

However, directly assign to the memory of an un-init pointer point to is indeed an undefined behavior.

Comment: declaration of variable in C and C++ must be preceded with `extern` keyword. This is full definition, with no initialization, hence the UB